# Как на сайте заблокировать F12?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, браузер

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии F12 на сайте не появлялось окно с исходным кодом?

Comment: перейти на другой браузер:)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005001/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-devtools-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1005644#1005644

Answer (score 12):

Никак.

Comment: И этот ответ стал топ-5 моих ответов по количеству плюсов.

Comment: вот поэтому я пишу некоторые "ответы" в комментарии :)

Comment: Потому что хороший ответ: кратко и по существу. У веб-программистов обычно есть иллюзия, что браузер пользователя им подчинён.

Comment: @VladD вы наверно не помните, что была такая фишка, которая ресайзила окно браузера и не позволяла его закрыть. А в окне играла веселая песенка и тикал счетчик.

Comment: @lampa: помню-помню, у меня для этого на тулбар вынесена кнопка «отключить js для этого таба [нафиг](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prefbar/)».

Answer (score 7):

Насчет кроссбраузерности не уверен, но в огнелисе работает.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    window.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        if(evt.keyCode == 123) return false;
    };

    window.onkeypress = function(evt) {
        if(evt.keyCode == 123) return false;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPD.** [демо](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MHLDT/2/show/)

Comment: Круто. Не знал, что браузер позволит так легко себя обмануть. Вот только заблокировать пункт Inspect Element из контекстного меню не получится никак (разве что написать сайт полностью на флеше или canvase'е, там можно запретить показ контекстного меню).

Comment: а что мешает заблокировать выбор контекстного меню?

Comment: Да, поспешил с выводами, его действительно можно заблокировать. Впрочем, от человека, которому _действительно_ интересно, как устроена страница, ничего скрыть не получится, такой человек всегда найдёт обходной путь.

Comment: window.onkeydown = function(evt) {if(evt.keyCode == 123){evt.preventDefault();}};

Comment: about:config -> dom.event.contextmenu.enabled := false помогает с context menu

Comment: с другой стороны, всегда есть curl/wget :)

Answer (score 3):

Ага. сначала F12, потом скажете нужно еще ctrl + u заблокировать, потом еще что-то..

Поэтому поддерживаю [@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus). Проще сразу сказать заказчику что такое сделать нельзя! :)

Comment: Поставил минус, так как сообщение не содержит ответ на поставленный вопрос

Comment: О, спасибо, не знал о ctrl + u.

Answer (score -1):

Ну так попробуй

```html
 document.onkeypress = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
           //alert('No F-12');
            return false;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            //alert('No F-keys');
            return false;
        }
    }
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            //alert('No F-keys');
            return false;
        }
    }

var message="Эх ты, мамке расскажу";

function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}}
function clickNS(e) {if
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}}
if (document.layers)
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;}
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;}
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")

function disableCtrlKeyCombination(e)
{

var forbiddenKeys = new Array('a', 'n', 'c', 'x', 'v', 'j' , 'w');
var key;
var isCtrl;
if(window.event)
{
key = window.event.keyCode;
if(window.event.ctrlKey)
isCtrl = true;
else
isCtrl = false;
}
else
{
key = e.which;
if(e.ctrlKey)
isCtrl = true;
else
isCtrl = false;
}
if(isCtrl)
{
for(i=0; i<forbiddenKeys.length; i++)
{
if(forbiddenKeys[i].toLowerCase() == String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase())
{
alert('Key combination CTRL + '+String.fromCharCode(key) +' has been disabled.');
return false;
}
}
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте еще одно такое же окно.

Вроде и не блокировка, но озадачит противника.

Для этого нужно попытаться отслеживать характерные изменения window.innerHeight, происходящие при открытии окна.

P.S. И зачем это апнули 4 года спустя...