# Как отследить DevTools состояние?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, браузер, google-chrome-devtools

Возможно ли по средствам JavaScript отследить что пользователь зашел на старицу с уже открытой панелью разработчика DevTools ? (не только для Chrome но и для других браузеров)

Comment: Нет, не хочу. Это скорее в область защиты собственного сайта

Comment: нет, это сделать не возможно, так как DevTools не является частью страницы и к ней нет никакого доступа

Comment: но можно попробовать узнать по косвенным признакам: [Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7809413/2881286)

Answer (score 5):

Вот такой способ, о котором я писал ранее в комментариях.

```js
function debuggerOpened() {
  console.log('debugger opened')
}

let last = Date.now()
setInterval(function() {
  debugger;
  let now = Date.now()
  now - last > 500 && debuggerOpened(); 
  last = now;
}, 10)
```

Comment: В Firefox не срабатывает почему-то,  и чёт оно очень агрессивно работает в Chrome и IE. (всё таки хотелось бы решение без setInterval)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 можно сделать так чтобы только 1 раз срабатывало

Comment: А теперь просто перейди на другую вкладку.

Comment: @Qwertiy напиши что происходит плз, а то я у десктопа буду только поздно ночью

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, хром замедляет таймеры в фотоных вкладках до 1 раза в секунду, насколько я помню.

Comment: Поставил Ваш код через setTimeout, и он почему-то перестал срабатывать http://prntscr.com/olmri5 (дебагер стопорит выполнение пользователю)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 ну так то в этом и смысл, открывший консоль нажимает на resume и вы тут же узнаете об этом, но не ранее:)

Comment: Эмм, а возможно это поправить ? Всё таки, задача именно и состоит в том что б пользователь не смог попасть в панель разработчика, а если его стопорит дебагер, и прям открывает перед ним эту панель, то это немного не то.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 я только лишь предложил что знаю, все другие способы которые раньше работали - перестали, вроже последнего предложенного

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать еще вот такой подход.

При открытом **DevTools** `console.log` будет работать медленнее, чем при закрытом.

Данный метод не очень хорошо работает в `Firefox`, там надо подобрать другие функции работы с консолью.

```js
const arr = new Array(5000).fill(Math.random().toString('36')).join(' ');
const delay = getDelay(arr) * 2;
delayTime.textContent = delay;
var isOpen = null;
setInterval(() => {
  const arr = new Array(5000).fill(Math.random().toString('36')).join(' ');
  const time = getDelay(arr);
  isOpen = time > delay;
  currentTime.textContent = time;
  consoleStatus.innerText = isOpen ? 'opened' : 'closed';
}, 1000);

function getDelay(data) {
  var t = performance.now();
  console.log(data);
  return performance.now() - t;
}
```

```html
<div id="consoleStatus"></div>
<div id="delayTime"></div>
<div id="currentTime"></div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96770/discussion-on-answer-by-stepan-kasyanenko---devtools-).

Answer (score 0):

Это решение использует тот факт, что toString() не вызывается для зарегистрированных объектов, если консоль не открыта.

```
var devtools = /./;
devtools.toString = function() {
  this.opened = true;
}

console.log('%c', devtools);
// devtools.opened will become true if/when the console is opened
```

Comment: Что-то не сработал ваш вариант, при открытие новой вкладке с уже открытым  DevTools. В консоль ничего не выдало

Comment: Вариант хороший, но работает только для хрома :-(