# Состояние консоли браузера

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли выяснить открыта ли консоль у браузера?

На сайте [дискорда](https://discordapp.com/) отслеживают ширину окна, ибо если сделать консоль в окне 
никакого сообщения не вылезет. Можно еще отслеживать нажатие клавиш "Ctrl+Shift+I", но если открыть консоль "Доп. инструменты -> Инструменты разработчика", так уже будет не отследить.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1005001

Comment: @Igor проблемы Y нет, зашел к ним на сайт, обратил внимание что контролят открытие консоли, и стало любопытно как еще это можно реализовать